# Matrix-matrix multiplication using einsum in Rust

Tags: rust

I would like to multiply arrays with random numbers using einsum. Here is the snip of my implementation:

```
 use ndarray_einsum_beta::*;
 use ndarray::Array;
 use ndarray_rand::RandomExt;
 use ndarray_rand::rand_distr::Uniform;

 fn main() {
   let m1 = Array::random((100, 100), Uniform::new(0., 10.));
   let m2 = Array::random((100, 100), Uniform::new(0., 10.));

   let res = einsum("ij,jk->ik", &[&m1, &m2]);
 }
```

While compiling the code, the following error message is thrown:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<{float}>, Dim<[usize; 2]>>: ArrayLike<_>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:11:37
  |
11 |   let res = einsum("ij,jk->ik", &[&m1, &m2]);
  |                   ^^^ the trait `ArrayLike<_>` is not implemented for `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<{float}>, Dim<[usize; 2]>>`
  |
  = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn ArrayLike<_>`
error[E0277]: the trait bound `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<{float}>, Dim<[usize; 2]>>: ArrayLike<_>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:11:42
  |
11 |   let res = einsum("ij,jk->ik", &[&m1, &m2]);
  |                      ^^^ the trait `ArrayLike<_>` is not implemented for `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<{float}>, Dim<[usize; 2]>>`
  |
  = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn ArrayLike<_>`
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `algebra_test`
```

It seems that I'm getting ArrayLike instead ArrayBase matrices.

Does anyone now what might cause this issue?

Here is the Cago.toml file content:

```
[dependencies]
ndarray = "0.14"
ndarray_einsum_beta = "0.4.4"
ndarray-rand = "0.13.0"
rand = "0.8"
```

Comment: What does your `Cargo.toml` look like? Can you include its contents  in the post? It does not seem to throw errors on my end with `ndarray@0.15.1`, `ndarray_einsum_beta@0.7.0` and `ndarray-rand@0.14.0`.

Comment: @Janson You're totally right. It was a matter of dependencies. Changing dependencies solves the problem.

Comment: Great to hear! I voted to close the question as "Not reproducible" so future readers will understand that it isn't an issue. Have a great weekend.

Comment: @Jason Thank you so much for your help! Have a great weekend too!